# cypress closing bootstrap modals

Tags: testing, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, cypress

When trying to close the modals they don't close.

I have several bootstrap modals that are called from different elements. To display them I do the following:

`cy.get('#units_modal').click()`

And the modal is displayed without problem.

The problem is when closing the modal. I want to close the dialog in the **after hook** when all the tests of that **describe** section have finished, I am putting:

```js
describe('Checking vehicles.', function(){
    before(()=>{
        cy.get('#unitsCommandHeaderMenu').click()
        cy.get('#units_modal').should('be.visible')
    })

    after(()=>{
        cy.get('#units_modal')    
        .then(($dialog)=>{
            cy.wrap($dialog).find('button').find('span').contains("×").click()
        });
    })

    it('first test', ()=> {
        cy.log('first test')
    })
    it('second test', ()=> {
        cy.log('second test')
    })
})
```

From the visual tool, when I put the pointer on the click event I see that the close button is being selected correctly and it should be clicking on it, but the modal does not close.

[image]
Even try the solution suggested by: [Closing an Angular Material Dialog in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854954/closing-an-angular-material-dialog-in-cypress)

This is my html code.

```html
<!-- buttons -->
<ul class="modal">
<li id="first" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#units_modal">
    <span>first</span>
</li>
<li id="second" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#second_modal">
    <span>second</span>
</li>
<li id="third" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#third_modal">
    <span>third</span>
</li>
</ul>


<!-- modals -->

<div class="modal fade" id="units_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="firstModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <!-- header -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body toFill">
            <!-- body -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-modal-update"><span class="modal-update-btn-spinner fa fa-refresh"></span><span class="modal-update-btn-text">Update</span></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-modal-add"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span><span class="modal-update-btn-text">Add</span></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="second_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="secondModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <!-- header -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body toFill">
                <!-- body -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="third_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="thirdModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <!-- header -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body toFill">
                <!-- body -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-thirdary btn-modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the "x" they have on the button is not the one you get from the keyboard.

I've shown both below so you can compare them.

```js
it('opens and closes the bootstrap modal', () => {
  cy.visit('https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/');

  cy.contains('Launch demo modal').click()

  cy.get('#exampleModalLive')  
    .should('be.visible')
    .find('.modal-header')
    .find('button[data-dismiss="modal"]')
    // .should('contain', 'x')             // ❌ fails  (char 120)
    .should('contain', '×')                // ✅ passes (char 215)
    .click()

  cy.get('#exampleModalLive')  
    .should('not.be.visible')
})
```

---

Actually, I just checked - you have the right "x", but the line that makes the difference seems to be

`.should('be.visible')`

after finding the modal (not checked exhaustively)

Maybe if you have more than just a `cy.log()` in the tests, the problem would not occur.

---

The visibility checks seem to make the test code wait for the fade animations to complete (see `class="modal fade show"` on the top element).